# wsdl2java generated class names

Tags: java, apache-axis, axis, wsdl2java

When I'm using wsdl2java tool to generate java classes based on wsdl file I get two files for each class: first - pure virtual class file, second - class file with implementation, which have Impl postfix in classname.

So, for example if I specify in wsdl message with name ServerMessage, then ServerMessage.java will be virtual and ServerMessageImpl.java will consist needed thing.

How should I use resulting files in non-generated code? I just want to use classes as specified in my wsdl file, but with such generation I'm forced to write Impl postfix after each class name. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I was playing with the wsdl2java and found the same thing.  I ended up installing the eclipse plugin, which seems to generate the classes much cleaner.  I'm curious as to why this is too, as most of my Web Services work is in C# and visual studio and it was an experiment on my part to generate a Java client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. Command line argument -uw did the trick.

> unwrap -
>   This will select between wrapped and unwrapped during code generation. Default is set to false. Maps to the -uw option of the command line tool.

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html